# Force gzip to decompress despite CRC error

Tags: java, gzip, compression

I think there's a way to do this but I'm not sure how? Basically, I was writing a compression program that resulted in a crc error when I tried to unzip the compressed data. Normally this means that the decompressor actually recognized my data as being in the right format and decompressed it, but when it compared the result to the expected length as indicated by the CRC, they weren't the same.

However, for comparison reasons, I actually do want to see the output to see if it's just a concatenation issue (which should be relatively obvious if the decompressed output isn't gibberish but just in the wrong order).

Comment: Not fully related to your topic but JFI: I removed crc from gz file and returned it from server with `Content-Encoding: gzip` and it was properly decompressed by Chrome and Firefox. Which means that browsers doesn't check the CRC. This is useful to serving precompressed files

Answer (score 20):

You said "unzip", but the question says "gzip".  Which is it?  Those are two different programs that operate on two different formats.  I will assume gzip.  Also the length is not "indicated by the CRC".  The gzip trailer contains a CRC and an uncompressed length (modulo 2<sup>32</sup>), which are two different things.

The `gzip` command will decompress all valid deflate data and write it out before checking the crc.  So if, for example, I take a `.gz` file and corrupt just the crc (or length) at the end, and do:

```
gzip -dc < corrupt.gz > result
```

then result will be the entire, correct uncompressed data stream.  There is no need to modify and recompile `gzip`, nor to write your own ungzipper.  gzip will complain about the crc, but all of the data will be written nevertheless.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I'm aware, the CRC check is part of the GZIP wrapper, not part of the actual compressed data in DEFLATE format.

So you should be able to take literally just the bytes that are the compressed data stream, ignoring the GZIP header and CRC at the end, and pass it through an Inflater.

In other words, you need to take just the bytes corresponding to those referred to as "compressed blocks" in the [GZIP File format specification](http://www.gzip.org/zlib/rfc-gzip.html) and try to decompress using a Java Inflater object. A little bit of work but possibly less than re-compiling the GZIP code as Greg suggests (though his option would also work in principle).