# zlib error -3 while decompressing archive: Incorrect data check

Tags: c++, zlib

I am writing a C++ library that also decompresses zlib files. For all of the files, the last call to `gzread()` (or at least one of the last calls) gives error -3 (`Z_DATA_ERROR`) with message "incorrect data check". As I have not created the files myself I am not entirely sure what is wrong.

I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13151632/1139324) answer and if I do

```
gzip -dc < myfile.gz > myfile.decomp
gzip: invalid compressed data--crc error
```

on the command line the contents of `myfile.decomp` seems to be correct. There is still the crc error printed in this case, however, which may or may not be the same problem. My code, pasted below, should be straightforward, but I am not sure how to get the same behavior in code as on the command line above.

How can I achieve the same behavior in code as on the command line?

```
std::vector<char> decompress(const std::string &path)
{
    gzFile inFileZ = gzopen(path.c_str(), "rb");
    if (inFileZ == NULL)
    {
        printf("Error: gzopen() failed for file %s.\n", path.c_str());
        return {};
    }

    constexpr size_t bufSize = 8192;
    char unzipBuffer[bufSize];
    int unzippedBytes = bufSize;

    std::vector<char> unzippedData;
    unzippedData.reserve(1048576); // 1 MiB is enough in most cases.

    while (unzippedBytes == bufSize)
    {
        unzippedBytes = gzread(inFileZ, unzipBuffer, bufSize);

        if (unzippedBytes == -1)
        {
            // Here the error is -3 / "incorrect data check" for (one of) the last block(s)
            // in the file. The bytes can be correctly decompressed, as demonstrated on the
            // command line, but how can this be achieved in code?
            int errnum;
            const char *err = gzerror(inFileZ, &errnum);
            printf(err, "%s\n");
            break;
        }

        if (unzippedBytes > 0)
        {
            unzippedData.insert(unzippedData.end(), unzipBuffer, unzipBuffer + unzippedBytes);
        }
    }

    gzclose(inFileZ);
    return unzippedData;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First off, the whole point of the CRC is to detect corrupted data. If the CRC is bad, then you should be going back to where this file came from and getting the data *not* corrupted. If the CRC is bad, discard the input and report an error.

You are not clear on the "behavior" you are trying to reproduce, but if you're trying to recover as much data as possible from a corrupted gzip file, then you will need to use zlib's inflate functions to decompress the file. `int ret = inflateInit2(&strm, 31);` will initialize the zlib stream to process a gzip file.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion, I will try it tonight. Unfortunately I do not control the how the files are created. They are save game files from [this mod](https://www.hota.acidcave.net/download.html) and their code is not open source. This is also the reason why it happens for all of my files, and also the reason why I would like to ignore the error. (This is also why I have a fair approximation for `std::vector::reserve()`.)

Comment: The `reserve` is not necessary, and likely excessive. The `unzippedData` vector will grow as needed.

Comment: Sure, it will grow, but when I have at least some clue as to what the final size will be I always call `reserve` to avoid continuous alloc/dealloc of memory up until the final size is reached.

Comment: Sure, but it looks like you in fact don't have a clue. There is no relation whatsoever between your buffer size and either the compressed size or the uncompressed size.